# Dataexporter get name of columns from bundle

Tags: jsf, pdf, primefaces

Hei guys,

I'm working on a primefaces app with loads of tables.

Right now, I'm looking into the dataexporter component and why it doesn't show the results correctly.

As an example, a column from a dataTable looks like this:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{r.code}" sortBy="#{r.code}">
    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.Column_code}</f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{r.code}" />
</p:column>
```

I'm executing this to generate the pdf:

```
<h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage library="images" name="pdf.png" />
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target=":form:stockDataTable"
        fileName="mypdf" pageOnly="true" />
</h:commandLink>
```

The resulting pdf looks like [THIS](http://i.imgur.com/Jd90kTE.jpg)

Is there any way I could get the messages from the ResourceBundle? also, how can the page be flipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
      <p:column headerText="#{msgs.Column_code}}" />
```

or

Did you look at this
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf;jsessionid=13qynorr7lp2x1guaz2s2nbifd

Comment: In PF3.5 the bundle messages as headers weren't supported. :)